# Python About regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have some question about using regular expression `re`
If I want to print processor time value `0.394519574284646` only in following contents

```
Readings       : \\demoweb01\processor(_total)\% processor time :

                 0.394519574284646





PSComputerName : DEMOWEB01

RunspaceId     : 8c9e3d4b-8908-4a30-bef4-1f26d4a511bb

Timestamp      : 4/3/2017 2:39:30 PM

CounterSamples : {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSa

                 mple}



Readings       : \\demoweb01\processor(_total)\% processor time :

                 1.69883362197086
```

It should try to find words after  `processor time :` ? Also, how to handle the space lines?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex that will take care of space & new lines as well -

```
r'processor\s+time\s*:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'
```

Sample run -

```
>>> output = """Readings       : \\demoweb01\processor(_total)\% processor time :
... 
...                  0.394519574284646
... 
... 
... 
... 
... 
... PSComputerName : DEMOWEB01
... 
... RunspaceId     : 8c9e3d4b-8908-4a30-bef4-1f26d4a511bb
... 
... Timestamp      : 4/3/2017 2:39:30 PM
... 
... CounterSamples : {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSa
... 
...                  mple}
... 
... 
... 
... Readings       : \\demoweb01\processor(_total)\% processor time :
... 
...                  1.69883362197086"""
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'processor\s+time\s*:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', output)
['0.394519574284646', '1.69883362197086']
```